# ImportError: cannot import name GdkX11

Tags: python, gtk3, pygobject

I'm a Windows developer and trying start PyGTK development. I want start with GTK+3 and folow this [documentation](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/PyGObject).

My environment:

- Windows 7 64bits
- Python 3.2 32bits
- [pygi-aio-3.10.2-win32_rev18-setup.exe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/files/?source=navbar)

My code:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import GdkX11
```

Error:

```
ERROR:root:Could not find any typelib for GdkX11
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 3.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1534, in <module>
    debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 3.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1145, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals) #execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 3.1\helpers\pydev\_pydev_execfile.py", line 37, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc) #execute the script
  File "Z:/git.repositories/gourmet-frontend/python/gourmet/main_gtk3.py", line 27, in <module>
    from gi.repository import GdkX11
ImportError: cannot import name GdkX11
```

When I install [pygi-aio-3.10.2-win32_rev18-setup.exe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/files/?source=navbar) I choose all options and check to downgrade to GTK+ 3.8.9.

Answer (score 2):

`GdkX11` is a platform-dependent library and only available (as the name suggests) on X11 platforms. You won't find it on Windows and you'll have to use a replacement.

Comment: Thanks. But what replacement I can use to get XID property in Windows environment? I'm trying port a code that need the integer id of window. I'm don't finding solution for this for PyGI library. In GTK+2 exists the Handle property of GtkWindow object.

Comment: I don't have a Windows environment available to verify, but from looking at the source I believe you can use `from gi.repository import GdkWin32` and `GdkWin32.window_get_impl_hwnd()`? See [this header file](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gdk/win32/gdkwin32misc.h) for more info.

Comment: when I try import GdkWin32 I get this error: ImportError: cannot import name GdkWin32